# How to name Cache-Aside function according to CQS principle

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture

For example, I have a function that retrieves data from cache or if the cache is empty, the function gets the result from DB or third-party API, and before returning, store the result to the cache (it looks like a primitive example of the Cache-Aside pattern).

```
public function getProductById(string $id): IProduct
{
    try {
        return $this->cache->getProductById($id);
    } catch (ProductDoesntExistException $e) {
        $product = $this->db->getProductById($id);
        $this->cache->saveProduct($product);

        return $product;
    }
}
```

So, according to the Command–query separation principle, we shouldn't do like this, but, let it be an exception.
When seeing the name like `getSometing` we expect that we don't change anything, but here we actually save cache. So, what is the best way of naming functions like this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there actually are not naming conventions attached to CQS.

Regarding your "how to square this circle" problem - I  think this comes from your misunderstanding of what is going on here.

According to CQS, the "getters" should not alter the thing that is being got or anything that "lives in the same realm" :) This is kinda the same as writing access logs - they too would be *writes*, but they too happen in a completely independent medium. The original state of the domain business model does not get altered.

**TL;DR:** the code itself is fine.

The issues that I do see are mostly in what everything else is being called:

- ID should be an `int` or a custom `UUID` value object
- interface should have valuable name describing "what does it act as", for example `Purchesable`
- extensiong dont need a suffix nameing them extensions, `ProductDoesntExist` is fine
- your `$this->db` should be a [data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) specifically name for persistence of products
- ... and this entire method should probably be inside of a repository (you might want to add an [identity map](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) at some point